# How to efficiently run negative binomial regression with many variables in R

Tags: r, regression, glm

My dataset shows negative binomial distribution, therefore, I want to use negative binomial regression to analyze it.

I followed the instruction described in this web site; https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/

Actually, it worked well, I was able to analyze my data.
However, I have many variable to analyze and I do not want to write a script as

`linear <- glm(V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8 + V9 + V10 ... V100, data = df1)`

Let's say if I have 100 variables to analyze, how can I write an efficient code for regression to save my time?
Although it works if I simply added everything like + V2 + V3 +V4.... till the end, I really do not want to.

Any comments should be helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: can't you just do ```linear <- glm(V1 ~ ., data = df1)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as.formula` and `paste` to the rescue

```
> Vmax=10
> as.formula(paste0("V1~",paste0("V",2:(Vmax-1),sep="+",collapse=""),"V",Vmax,collapse=""))

V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4 + V5 + V6 + V7 + V8 + V9 + V10
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I got an exactly the same result.
I do memorize the combination of as.formula with paste for future use.